# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server на локальном сервере?

Tags: apache, веб-сервер

Столкнулся с проблемой, после того как в файле `httdp-vhosts.conf` дописал виртуальный хост, то я перестал получать доступ к `http://localhost/`
Я решил прописать в том же файле и доступ к `localhost`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Server/data/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>`

Но это ничего не дало, доступ я не могу получить при заходе пишет

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

В чем может быть ошибка. P.S. Ось Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте теги **Directory**:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "D:/Server/data/htdocs/"
        ServerName localhost
        <Directory "D:/Server/data/htdocs">
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Увы, но это не помогает

Comment: @Mr.Flatman А какая версия Апача? Добавьте еще внутрь тэга Directory такое: Require all granted

Comment: апач 2.4, после перезагрузки стал пускать, то ли это гулюк апача был, то ли ваш способ помог , но после полной перезагрузки пк заработало наконец-то, теперь имею доступ)